# Поддерживает ли tp-link TL-WN822N инъекцию и мониторинг?

Tags: kali-linux, электроника

Здравствуйте уважаемые пользователи форума. Может ли кто подсказать о возможностях Wifi адаптера tp-link TL-WN822N v5.20? Дело в том что решил начать практиковаться в сфере пентестинга, однако одним из важнейших компонентов является Wifi адаптер который поддерживает инъекцию и режим мониторинга. Может ли данная приблуда поддерживать перечисленные мною фишки? Если нет, то какой вы бы могли посоветовать по бюджету студента?

Answer (score 0):

судя по данным с сайта https://wikidevi.wi-cat.ru/Rtl8xxxu
у модели `TP-LINK TL-WN822N v5` установлен чип `RTL8192EU` 2016 года выпуска.

а на том же форуме reddit/kalilinux в [этой теме](https://www.reddit.com/r/Kalilinux/comments/mp94lh/does_the_rtl8192eu_support_monitoring_mode/) людям так и не удалось заставить его нормаль работать в режиме мониторинга. В общем если не хотите сыграть в лотерею с вышеописанным адаптером то лучше присмотреть что-то другое.

> Если нет, то какой вы бы могли посоветовать по бюджету студента?

в своё время когда подбирал адаптер то наткнулся на довольно [интересный материал на github-e](https://github.com/morrownr/USB-WiFi/) по данной тематике, если хотите быть уверены в покупке то гляньте их [Short_List](https://github.com/morrownr/USB-WiFi/blob/main/home/The_Short_List.md)